# What does Integrated information theory tell us about non-biological consciousness?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

What does IIT have to say about consciousness in rocks, stars or atoms?

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing coherent. Its Phi metric does assign low value to some inanimate objects, and high value to human brains, but it also assigns high value to systems of gates that perform parity checks or multiply matrices by vectors, see [Aaronson's blog](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1799) and [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/int-info/#SH5b). "*We seem to have the intuition that global integration of information is such a powerful property that no “simple” or “mundane” computational process could possibly achieve it. But our intuition is wrong.*" Until the metric is fixed IIT won't say much.

Comment: I am really alarmed by the mood of this section of philosophy, someone wants to become a god, someone wants to awaken consciousness in a stone. Consciousness can be understood in a broader or narrower sense. For example, from the point of view of the theory of reflection, consciousness in the broad sense is "a mental reflection of reality, regardless of at what level it is carried out - biological or social, sensory or rational", and in the narrow sense - "the highest function of the brain, peculiar only to people and associated with the ability to explain thoughts, which consists in a general

Comment: @Conifold Perhaps a matrix multiplication computer is indeed conscious in the sense of having subjective sensory experiences; on what basis would you claim otherwise?  Too often on the subject of consciousness we see the fallacy of "[appeal to the stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_the_stone)" - in this case often literally saying "but of course a stone cannot be conscious!" with no justification given.  Lack of higher cognitive functions is not a problem, unless you claim the higher functions are necessary for sensory qualia, and that's a hard thing to justify.

Comment: Also these close votes are inappropriate.  Whether you agree with them or not, IIT and panpsychism are both legitimate subjects in philosophy.  "I disagree, so close the question" is not legitimate.

Comment: @causative That's not the problem. IIT cannot claim success with "explaining" consciousness of brain parts, on the basis that they are "intuitively" conscious, and then shrug off failure with parity checkers, on the basis that intuition "doesn't matter". The dilemma makes it either baseless or falsified (in current form). But it does have the right structure of a promising theory. It just needs metric(s) that actually correlate with the target phenomenon, and discriminative explanations of counterintuitive cases that do not explain too much by "maybe intuition is wrong".

Comment: Btw, I voted to close because OP are expected to do some prior reading and post more than vague one-liners.

Comment: @Conifold Intuition is not innate or monolithic. We form intuitions based on training and experience, and based on thinking about a subject for a long time. What is counterintuitive initially in a subject (e.g. math, physics, aircraft piloting) may become intuitive after much practice. It's fine if IIT is based on *certain* intuitions that it takes as fundamental, while discarding *other* intuitions as contradicted by the more fundamental ones. To be consistent with *all* intuitions is an impossible standard for any theory in any subject.

Comment: @causative And that is a fine argument, as long as it does not stop at generalities. What Tononi needs is a specific theory that sorts out intuitions, and matches IIT to those selected by some independent criteria. Like what Kripke did for modal intuitions. But so far he did not offer that, what we get is a circular: X is conscious whenever IIT says it is conscious. One can make a "theory" that X is conscious whenever its temperature is around 98.6°F and claim "success" at explaining brains too, then use the same generalities about intuitions to answer objections.

Comment: @Conifold Well, I don't exactly subscribe to IIT, but the core premise that consciousness requires *thorough interaction* between its parts, seems sound and intuitive to me. The chief problem I see with IIT is that it is based on probability distributions over states of the agent - but where do these distributions come from?  Probability is subjective. I would like to see a theory that defines this "thorough interaction" in a non-probabilistic way.

Comment: This does amount to 'What is IIT?' which can be addressed through general articles, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory (better than SEP on this topic). It seems a pretty rudimentary theory, so far.